# Eclipse Android Runtime Errors twitter feed

Tags: android, eclipse, runtime

I am new to eclipse and have been trying to integrate a twitter feed into my app, using the tutorial from http://javapapers.com/android/android-twitter-feed-reader/.

Having followed the tutorial, when running the app I get many errors.

07-23 20:40:01.348: D/dalvikvm(898): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
07-23 20:40:03.188: E/Trace(898): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-23 20:40:04.478: D/dalvikvm(898): GC_CONCURRENT freed 68K, 5% free 2731K/2860K, paused 20ms+13ms, total 96ms
07-23 20:40:04.568: D/AndroidRuntime(898): Shutting down VM
07-23 20:40:04.568: W/dalvikvm(898): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.witsbuses/com.example.witsbuses.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:273)
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.example.witsbuses.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-23 20:40:04.598: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  ... 11 more

Could you kindly assist. I'm not sure what code would be required, so please do inform me if you need to see any.

Comment: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: Is this correct?                                                                                    <ListView 
     android:id="@+id/android.R.id.list"